# Error cuando ejecuto el MAKEFILE

Tags: c++, makefile, make

Si la pregunta esta mal formulada sean libres de editarla

Tengo el siguiente MAKEFILE para compilar mi programa:

```
CXX = g++
V8 = engine/lib/v8

define INCLUDE
    $(V8)/include
    engine/Core.cpp
    engine/Environment.cpp
    engine/Lemon.cpp
    engine/StaticHelpers.cpp
    engine/ObjectCreator.cpp
endef

define APP
    app/*.cpp
endef

define LIB
    $(V8)/out/x64.release/obj/
endef

define OBJ
    v8_monolith
endef

export INCLUDE
export APP
export LIB
export OBJ

build:
    $(CXX) -I $$INCLUDE $$APP -L $$LIB -l $$OBJ -std=c++0x -pthread -o lemon
```

Pero me da el siguiente error al ejecutarlo:

> g++: error: $APP: No such file or directory

¿A que se debe este error?

Comment: Prueba a cambiar cosas como `$$APP` por `$(APP)` (y las restantes con `$$`)

Comment: Funciono gracias

Comment: El doble $ sirve para que make no "expanda" ese carácter, sino que se lo pase "tal cual" al comando. Por ello `g++` recibía un parámetro `$APP` que no entendía (en vez de recibir el valor que sería `app/*.cpp`)